# Should I be honest in a temp job interview about continuing to seek full-time employment?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I have an upcoming interview for a temporary job that will last a few months (or potentially more depending on funding). I have a good vibe about them and I think chances are good that they like me enough that they will hire me based on my previous phone interview.

I do not intend to suspend my search for a full-time job even if they hire me. My preference is always to get a full-time job.

Just being honest, if employed by them, I still intend to continue interviewing for full-time positions. If I happen to get a full-time gig before the term is up, I will most likely leave. I want to be transparent about my priorities but I see how this can be counted as a negative.

Should I be honest about this with them in the interview? I need a job -- short or long term -- I have bills to pay. But, ideally, I also want to be transparent.

Comment: Is expected, to a certain extent, though I've had potential short-term employers ask for a certain minimum time commitment (just my word of honor) - they'd like me to be there 6 to 12 months, can I commit to at least four?  That kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

Let them know that you would like to seek full-time employment **WITH THEM.**  Then, do so.

Look for other venues, but of course, don't tell them at the time.

Anyone who hires you for a temp position doesn't expect that you will drop off the face of the earth or retire as soon as the job ends, so it's a given that you will be looking.  Letting them know that you'd want to work for them FT is a good way to get a perm job.